# Update value of a object in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update a specific value based on the id in a data array. I'm trying to do this inside my reducer in redux.

For example what i need is something like this

```
            case STATION_SELECT:
            const checkedGroupData = (data,id) => {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(id);
            }

            return {
                ...state,
                chargingStationGroups: Object.values(checkedGroupData(state.chargingStationGroups,action.id)),
            }
```

So here console.log value for `data` is like below

```
[
  0: 
     groupId: "31"
     groupName: "Test"
     stations: [
       0: {stationID: "26",name: "TestName",checked:false}
       1: {stationID: "28",name: "TestName2",checked:false}
     ]
  1: 
     groupId: "32"
     groupName: "Test332"
     stations: [
       0: {stationID: "29",name: "TestName1212",checked:false}
       1: {stationID: "30",name: "TestName122",checked:false}
     ]

]
```

so if my console.log for id is `26` how can i change the `checked:false` to `checked:true` for `stationID: 26`

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested `Array.map` and check for `stationID` if it matches the `id` return `true`, if not, return the original one :

```js
const checkedGroupData = (data, id) => {
  return data.map(o => ({
    ...o,
    stations: o.stations.map(s => ({
      ...s,
      checked: s.stationID === id ? true : s.checked
    }))
  }));
};

const data = [
  {
    groupId: "31",
    groupName: "Test",
    stations: [
      { stationID: "26", name: "TestName", checked: false },
      { stationID: "28", name: "TestName2", checked: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    groupId: "32",
    groupName: "Test332",
    stations: [
      { stationID: "29", name: "TestName1212", checked: false },
      { stationID: "30", name: "TestName122", checked: false }
    ]
  }
];

const result = checkedGroupData(data, "26");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This sets the Boolean property `checked` to the string value of `stationID`, which seems... odd. Wouldn't it be better to use `checked: s.stationID === id`?

Comment: Although this solution changes the checked status, it does not hold the checked status. When i click on another checkbox, that particular checkbox gets checked and the other checkbox will uncheck. How can i handle this?

Comment: @HereticMonkey my bad, i guess i wrote it too fast, i fixed it, i think `checked: s.stationID === id` can override the `checked` to `false` on all the other objects that doesn't match the `id` and might have `checked:true`, i prefere to keep the original value.

Comment: @CraZyDroiD try the updated the answer, it had a mistake in it,